# Features are not being generated for my Entityset Set Up in featuretools

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-engineering, featuretools

I encountered a problem when I tried to create relationships between entititysets (using my own data). There is no error, but it just doesn't create features for one of my entities (the "prods" entity), although everything should be connected just fine.

I can't share my data but I created a minimal example with some mock data:

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft
```

Create Mock Data

```
cust = pd.DataFrame([[1,50],[2,60]], 
                    columns=['CUST_ID','AGE'])#

orders = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,50,33.0],[2,1,60,20],[3,2,66,999.9]], 
                      columns=['ORD_ID','CUST_ID','QTY','PRICE'])

order_items = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,2,3.0],[2,2,2,8,5.0],[3,2,1,2,3.0],[4,3,3,2,3.0]], 
                           columns=['ORD_ITM_ID','ORD_ID','PROD_ID','QTY','PRICE'])

prods = pd.DataFrame([[1,3.0],[2,5.0],[3,3.0]], 
                     columns=['PROD_ID','PRICE'])
```

Defining Entity Set

```
es = ft.EntitySet('test')

## Adding Customers Entity

es.entity_from_dataframe(dataframe=cust,
                         entity_id='cust',
                         index='CUST_ID')

## Adding Orders Entity
es.entity_from_dataframe(dataframe=orders,
                         entity_id='orders',
                         index='ORD_ID')

## Adding Order Items Entity
es.entity_from_dataframe(dataframe=order_items,
                         entity_id='order_items',
                         index='ORD_ITM_ID')

## Adding Products Entity
es.entity_from_dataframe(dataframe=prods,
                         entity_id='prods',
                         index='PROD_ID')
```

Create Relationships

```
customer_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["cust"]["CUST_ID"],
                                   es["orders"]["CUST_ID"])


orderitems_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["orders"]["ORD_ID"], 
                                          es["order_items"]["ORD_ID"])


products_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["prods"]["PROD_ID"],
                                        es["order_items"]["PROD_ID"])

### Add Relationships
es = es.add_relationship(customer_relationship)
es = es.add_relationship(orderitems_relationship)
es = es.add_relationship(products_relationship)
```

Generate Features

```
feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                target_entity="cust",
                                agg_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                                verbose = True, 
                                features_only = True)
## Show features
feature_defs
```

Output:

```
Built 7 features
[<Feature: AGE>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.QTY)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(orders)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE)>]
```

This should show me features for product variables too, but it doesn't.

So what I would expect is that SUM would sum the product price per customer. Instead, there is nothing.

Ultimately, I wanted to create features for interesting values. But since product variables don't show up, adding interesting values also doesn't work.

```
## Get All Product IDs
interesting_products = es["prods"].df.PROD_ID.unique()

es["prods"]["PROD_ID"].interesting_values=interesting_products


feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                target_entity="cust",
                                agg_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                                where_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                                verbose = True, 
                                features_only = True)
## Show features
feature_defs
```

Output:

```
Built 7 features
[<Feature: AGE>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.QTY)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(orders)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE)>]
```

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is product isn't showing up is because any features created from it would be depth 3. You can control the depth in `ft.dfs` using the `max_depth` parameter like this

```
feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                      target_entity="cust",
                      agg_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                      verbose = True, 
                      max_depth=3, # add max_depth
                      features_only = True)
```

Now the features that get returned are

```
[<Feature: AGE>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.QTY)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(orders)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE)>]
```

You can see `SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE)` at the end using the products price.

To get the where clauses to work, add the interesting values to the `order_items` entity instead.

```
interesting_products = es["prods"].df.PROD_ID.unique()
es["order_items"]["PROD_ID"].interesting_values=interesting_products
feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                      target_entity="cust",
                      agg_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                      where_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                      verbose=True, 
                      max_depth=3, 
                      features_only=True)
```

this creates 20 features, which you can see below

```
[<Feature: AGE>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: SUM(orders.QTY)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(orders)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 2)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY WHERE PROD_ID = 2)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY WHERE PROD_ID = 3)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items WHERE PROD_ID = 2)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 1)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 3)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items WHERE PROD_ID = 1)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(order_items WHERE PROD_ID = 3)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.prods.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 3)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.QTY WHERE PROD_ID = 1)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 2)>,
 <Feature: SUM(order_items.PRICE WHERE PROD_ID = 1)>]
```